# How to convert data into column and create CSV file in Linux using single line Perl commands

Tags: linux, perl

I have text file something like this

```
Name : Harsha
Class : 12
Hobby : dance 
Name : Nikhil
Class : 11
Hobby : sing
Name : akhil
Class :10
Hobby : Gym
```

How do I create a CSV file with three columns - `name`, `class`, and `hobby` using `Perl -0pe command one-liner`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
perl -F'/\s*:\s*/' -E'
    chomp $F[1]; 
    /^Name/ && push @name, $F[1];
    /^Class/ && push @class, $F[1];
    /^Hobby/ && push @hobby, $F[1];
    END {say join ",", $name[$_], $class[$_], $hobby[$_] for 0..$#name}
' input.txt
```

or alternatively:

```
perl -nE '
    ($_, $v) = /^(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)/;
    /Name/ && push @name, $v;
    /Class/ && push @class, $v;
    /Hobby/ && push @hobby, $v; 
    END {say join ",", $name[$_], $class[$_], $hobby[$_] for 0..$#name}
' input.txt
```

**Output**:

```
Harsha,12,dance 
Nikhil,11,sing
akhil,10,Gym
```

Answer (score 1):

As `-0pe` was asked for:

```perl
perl -0pe 's/^Hobby *: *//mg; s/^(.+?) *: *(.+)\n/$2,/mg'
```

Explanation:

Due to `-0` all the input is "slurped" into `$_`. So what is the regexp doing?

1. `s/^Hobby *: *//mg;` This will simply remove the "Tag" `Hobby` and the following colon and spaces.
2. `s/^(.+?) *: *(.+)\n/$2,/mg` This will remove every other "Tag" and its colon and possible spaces, which is found, `(.+?) *: *`. Then it will remember all the text following `(.+)` and remove the trailing lineend. It will replace it with the text found and a comma.

So in essence I'm removing all the tags and lineends. All lineends are replaced by a comma, except for the "Hobby"-line which is the last line of an entry. Here the linefeed remains.

Of course this is by far not bulletproof, but I thought it's enough for you to think about, since you didn't show any attempt of solving it on your own I didn't want to overwhelm you with the most sophisticated script which could also handle wrong sequences in your input data or missing data or data which contains additional colons.

That's left as an excercise for you.

Have fun…

Comment: can you please explain this

Comment: Sure. Will do so in the post to be able to use formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use a library to create CSV files so you don't create a broken CSV or end up with the wrong data when you run into edge cases. The csv function from [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) is nice for oneliners.

```
perl -CS -MText::CSV=csv -ne'chomp; my ($n, $v) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2;
  $row{$n} = $v; if ($n eq "Hobby") { push @rows, {%row}; %row = () }
  END { csv(in => \@rows, out => \*STDOUT, headers => [qw(Name Class Hobby)],
    auto_diag => 2) }' input.txt
```